# calculate NPV, PPV, sensitivity, specificity when new_outcome == 1

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I am a graduate student with a master's degree in Korea. So maybe you feel awkward for my sentence. Anyway, I have a data.

```
       new_outcome   A      B      C
1:           0       0      1      1
2:           0       0      0      0
3:           0       0      0      0
4:           0       0      0      0
5:           0       0      0      0
6:           0       0      1      0
```

So I want to calculate NPV, PPV, sensitivity, specificity when new_outcome == 1.
I quest to google, chatGPT. But I don't acquire answer that I want.

Help me TnT

I tried..

```
data_sub <- subset(mydata, new_outcome == 1)
```

## Create a confusion matrix

```
conf_mat <- confusionMatrix(factor(data_sub$new_outcome), factor(ifelse(data_sub$A + data_sub$B+ data_sub$C >= 2, 1, 0)))
```

## Calculate metrics

```
NPV <- conf_mat$byClass[["Neg Pred Value"]]
PPV <- conf_mat$byClass[["Pos Pred Value"]]
sensitivity <- conf_mat$byClass[["Sensitivity"]]
specificity <- conf_mat$byClass[["Specificity"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
conf_mat <- caret::confusionMatrix(mydata$new_outcome, factor(+(rowSums(mydata[,-1]) >= 2)), "1")
conf_mat$byClass[["Neg Pred Value"]]
#> [1] 0.6666667
conf_mat$byClass[["Pos Pred Value"]]
#> [1] 0.8181818
conf_mat$byClass[["Sensitivity"]]
#> [1] 0.75
conf_mat$byClass[["Specificity"]]
#> [1] 0.75
```

Data

```
set.seed(52108973)
mydata <- data.frame(
  A = sample(0:1, 20, 1),
  B = sample(0:1, 20, 1),
  C = sample(0:1, 20, 1)
)
mydata$new_outcome <- as.factor(rbinom(20, 1, rowSums(mydata)/3))
mydata <- mydata[,c(4L, 1:3)]
```